# Бэкграунд на несколько блоков

Tags: css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть два блока (белый и фиолетовый), внутри белого есть оранжевый относительно которого нужно разместить бэкграунд картинку (зеленый круг). Макет резиновый, следовательно если ширина экрана больше 1200px, то зеленый круг полный, если экран сужается, то круг обрезается по ширине экрана, но так же он двигается за оранжевым блоком, т.к. оранжевый резиновый.

Пробовал через псевдоэлемент прикрепить к оранжевому блоку, но тогда если экран сужается и круг не помещается, то появляется горизонтальная полоса прокрутки.

P.S. overflow-x: hidden применять нельзя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код примерно такой: https://codepen.io/nomiy/pen/eYmNGNj

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="block1-cont"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```

```
.block1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.block1-cont {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff7f27;
  position: relative;
}

.block1-cont::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #22b14c;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #c8bfe7;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/nomiy/pen/eYmNGNj

Comment: Можно не только CSS, можно HTML менять. Если вообще никак, тогда JS, но это уже будет сложно наверное...

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста вариант с js?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  var $body = $(document);
  $body.bind('scroll', function() {
    if ($body.scrollLeft() !== 0) {
      $body.scrollLeft(0);
    }
  });
});
document.documentElement.style.overflowX = 'hidden'; // Или скрыть полностью
```

```css
.block1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

.block1-cont {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff7f27;
  position: relative;
}

.block1-cont::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #22b14c;
  z-index: -1;
}

.block2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 300px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #c8bfe7;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="block1">
    <div class="block1-cont" id="goriz"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>
```